# Возврат json с php в ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Всем привет. Ребят, застрял, помогите решить проблему. Из select name="enterplow" получаю данные и с помощью jQuery отправляю на php код. с php возвращаю json_encode($result) в jQuery. После обработки получаю абрукадабру, а не желаемый результат. В ajax новичок. Перекопал гугл, но варианта решения не нашел. если закомментировать if (data != 0) {
        data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        for (var data in data) {
          $('select[name="tract"]').append("" + data['title'] + "");
        }
      } то в консоль получаю {"title":"JCB Fastrac 3000 Xtra"}{"title":"NEW HOLLAND T8"} т.е. то, что нужно. если правильно все понимаю

```js
// php код
<?php
$us_ses_id = $_SESSION['id'];
$plows = $_POST['plows'];
if ($plows == '') {
echo "Сделайте выбор!";
}
else {
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT engine_kvt, engine_ls FROM equipment_of_users WHERE user_id = $us_ses_id AND title = '$plows'");
while ($result = $stmt->fetch())
{
$GLOBALS['kvtplow'] = $result['engine_kvt'];
$GLOBALS['lsplow'] = $result['engine_ls'];
}
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM equipment_of_users WHERE user_id = $us_ses_id AND subtitle = 'трактор' AND engine_kvt >= $kvtplow AND engine_ls >= $lsplow");

while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) 
{
$GLOBALS['res'] = $result[0];
}
if ($res != 0) {
echo $res;
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT title FROM equipment_of_users WHERE user_id = $us_ses_id AND subtitle = 'трактор' AND engine_kvt >= $kvtplow AND engine_ls >= $lsplow");
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
<?= json_encode($result); ?> <<
?
endwhile;
}
else {
  $eroors = 'У Вас в наличии нет подходящего трактора.<br> <a href="tractors" style="color: green;">купить</a>';
  echo $eroors;
}
} ?
>
// jQuery код
$(document).ready(function() {
  $errors = $('span.errors');
  $spanselect = $('span.select');
  $enterplow = $('select[name="enterplow"]');
  $enterplow.bind('change', function() {
    $.post('../fieldfunc', {
      plows: $enterplow.val()
    }, function(data) {
      if (data == "Сделайте выбор!") {
        $errors.text(data);
      }
      if (data == 'У Вас в наличии нет подходящего трактора.<br> <a href="tractors" style="color: green;">купить</a>') {
        $errors.html(data);
      }
      if (data != 0) {
        data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        for (var data in data) {
          $('select[name="tract"]').append("<option value=" + data + ">" + data['title'] + "</option>");
        }
      }
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="enterplow">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="Amazone Cayron 200">Amazone Cayron 200</option>
  <option value="Salford 8312">Salford 8312</option>
</select>
// после обработки получаю
<select name="tract">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="0">undefined</option>
  <option value="1">undefined</option>
  <option value="2">undefined</option>
  <option value="3">undefined</option>
  <option value="4">undefined</option>
  <option value="5">undefined</option>
  <option value="6">undefined</option>
  ..............
  <option value="59">undefined</option>
</select>
```

Comment: 1) `JSON.parse()` вторым аргументом принимает коллбэк. 2) `jQuery.post()` четвертым аргументом - тип возвращаемых данных `HTML | JSON` (если указать `JSON`, то можно не применять `JSON.parse()`). 3) `data['title']` - тут обращение как к массиву, а`JSON.parse()` создает объект (соответственно обращение к свойству объекта в JS - `data.title`)

Comment: >user-2147482225 подправил код. добавил в $.post последним параметром 'json' и data = JSON.stringify(data) убрал JSON.parse но теперь на выходе вообще ничего не получаю.

Comment: потому что бэкенд возвращает невалидный JSON. сначала создаем массив данных, затем конвертируем в JSON (за пределами цикла) `$data = array();
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 $data[] = $result;
}
echo json_encode($result);`

Comment: echo json_encode($data) иначе он точно ничего не передаст. и передает [{"title":"JCB Fastrac 3000 Xtra"},{"title":"NEW HOLLAND T8"}] но реакции все равно никакой. в js ничего не менял.

Comment: теперь `data` - массив объектов `if(data != 0){
  $.each(data,function(){
   console.log(this);
   console.log(this.title);
  });
 }`

Comment: битый час пляски с кодом и все равно никакого результата. убрал с $.post 'json' + JSON.parse = Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) о чем речь эт понятно. при JSON.stringify = Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in "2[{\"title\":\"JCB Fastrac 3000 Xtra\"},{\"title\":\"NEW HOLLAND T8\"}]" тоже беда. если ничего не менять, то в консоли вообще ничего нету. мозг взорван. Ребят, есть еще какие то мысли?)))

Answer (score 0):

можно еще так попробовать

в PHP:

```
$data = array(); 
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    $data[] = $result; 
} 
exit(json_encode($data));
```

``

в jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $errors = $('span.errors');
    $spanselect = $('span.select');
    $enterplow = $('select[name="enterplow"]');
    $enterplow.bind('change', function() {
        $.post('../fieldfunc', {
            plows: $enterplow.val()
        }, function(data) {
            if (data == "Сделайте выбор!") {
                $errors.text(data);
            }
            if (data == 'У Вас в наличии нет подходящего трактора.<br> <a href="tractors" style="color: green;">купить</a>') {
                $errors.html(data);
            }
            if (data != 0) {
                $.each(data,function(key,value){
                    $('select[name="tract"]').append("<option value=" + key + ">" + this.title + "</option>")
                });
                console.log(data);
            }
            console.log(data);
        },'json');
    });
});
```

Comment: >user-2147482225 ничего не меняется..